# How do I get a column to appear in DIP (word document) but not on the SP edit item form?

Tags: word, document-info-panel, dip

I have a column which I want to use in a word document, however when I make the column hidden so that it does not appear on the edit form in sharepoint - it also hides it from the Word Insert -> Document Property panel.

This column contains a reference number, which I cannot let the user change, so I really don't want it on any form, but I do want it available to the document in Word.

I have noticed that I can have the column as optional, then add it to Word, and then hide it again, it will work - however this causes issues for all new documents.

Comment: what's the problem with hiding it? If you let the column appear in DIP and user changes it there thats ok for you? because this will synchronize with sharepoint and it will be changed there also.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so in JavaScript using JSLink, this way, the field will be hidden only from forms. Check an example here:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-a52cf8a7

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy way would be to create a new EditForm in the Document library through SharePoint Designer and edit this in the advanced mode you will see the html for relevant fields.  You can hide it through CSS e.g.

I tested this with SharePoint Online and the field is hidden on the editform but appearing the word information panel. If this is how you wanted?